# Jenkins ANT uses wrong target during invocation

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins, github-api

I am attempting to invoke ant from jenkins job and the command in the console looks like this. [Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQICs.png)

The target value in the error (redacted by red in the image) is actually *username/repository-name* - even though I specified a different target "validateWithoutTestsCommon" in the configuration.

1. Why is it selecting wrong target even though the command in the console states the target value ? [see Console log image linked] How can i fix it?
2. I see many environment variables in the console which were injected by Github Pull Request builder plugin. Without removing Github Pull Request Builder plugin - Is it possible to not include those environment variables in the ant invocation ?

Already tried:

1. checking if build.xml being used was wrong somehow. It is using the correct build.xml file.
2. commenting out lines from build.xml 'property file="build.properties"
   property environment="env"'. No effect.
3. checking the global and tool configuration for any indication of override settings. None found.

Comment: The terminal is interpreting part of your URL value as the target before it reads the target at the end. Try putting those parameters in quotes the same way you did with the params that contain spaces.